# mktorrent not working on Windows

Tags: mingw

I'm trying to get mktorrent working on Windows. I've compiled both 32-bit and 64-bit versions using MinGW, and the program compiles and executes flawlessly. However, for some reason, it lists the size of the file as a huge negative number. I'm testing on a single file, so mktorrent is getting filesizes using stat() in sys/stat.h.

Is there any specific reason this is not working? Maybe's it's MingGW's fault?

Answer (score 0):

No problem with MinGW, propbably configure script ran in full or FAT disk and could not make 4GB+1K test file.